# how to select and print from each variable in another select sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this query and get a list of company names in many rows (each name in one row)

```
select distinct companyName from Companies
```

from each name I can use this query to get another property related to that company name:

```
 SELECT distinct 
 STUFF((SELECT ', '+ cn.name  
        from WMCCMCategories cn  
        INNER JOIN CategorySets uc 
        ON uc.categoryId = cn.categoryID 
        INNER JOIN KeyProcesses u 
        ON u.categorySetId = uc.setId  
        INNER JOIN Companies c 
        ON c.companyId = u.companyId  
        WHERE c.companyName = @companyName  
        ORDER BY cn.name FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr 
FROM WMCCMCategories cnn 
Group by cnn.name
```

Now, I want to apply that query for each name in the first query, so I replace @companyName by that first query:

```
SELECT distinct 
    STUFF((SELECT ', '+ cn.name  
           from WMCCMCategories cn  
           INNER JOIN CategorySets uc ON uc.categoryId = cn.categoryID 
           INNER JOIN KeyProcesses u ON u.categorySetId = uc.setId  
           INNER JOIN Companies c ON c.companyId = u.companyId  
           WHERE c.companyName in 
                 (select distinct companyName from Companies)
           ORDER BY cn.name FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr 
FROM 
    WMCCMCategories cnn 
GROUP BY 
    cnn.name
```

But it will print all the results in one row. What I need is the result for each company names in one rows, and I can get each properties for each company Names. How could I modify to get that ?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Comment: ok modified the tag. tks! how about the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write as:

```
SELECT distinct
 c1.companyName,
 STUFF((SELECT ', '+ cn.name  
        from WMCCMCategories cn  
        INNER JOIN CategorySets uc 
        ON uc.categoryId = cn.categoryID 
        INNER JOIN KeyProcesses u 
        ON u.categorySetId = uc.setId  
        INNER JOIN Companies c 
        ON c.companyId = u.companyId        
        WHERE c.companyName = c1.companyName 
        ORDER BY cn.name FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr 
FROM Companies c1
Group by c1.companyName
```

Comment: seems like ur SQL expert :)